# How to access custom helper/function on storybook?

Tags: next.js, storybook, nextjs-storybook

js,

I want to ask how to access some custom function that I use on my components ?

Here my component Code :
[see image here

[image: 1]

Currently my component have 2 helper, and load from "../app/helpers"

Here my storiesbook for that component :
see image here

[image: 2]

And I got this error when running yarn storybook
see image here

[image: 3]

Please anyone can give me some advice for this problem ?

Thanks